# Return cell row and column of a cell after using find

Tags: vba, excel, find, row

I am searching for a VBA command that in combination with `find()` (or similar) returns the address of the found cell in a fixed column.

Due to the programm, the value I am searching for exists only once, but apparently I could only return its value, not its location.

```vb
 Set Cell = Selection.Find(What:=Choice, LookIn:=xlFormulas,_
 LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext,_
 MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

It is probably an easy question, but help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write after your code:

```
debug.print cell.row
debug.print cell.column
```